# Why does writing a $ before a string affect how bash interprets backslashes in it?

Tags: bash

Today I encountered this:

```sh
$ echo $'foo\\n'
foo\n
$ echo 'foo\\n'
foo\\n
```

I have never come across this before and never heard anyone mention this. I would've expected `$` outside of strings to cause that string to be treated as a variable name. Where is this documented and has it always been this way?

Comment: Tip: To find this in your system's built-in bash(1) man page, type `man bash` and then type `/\$\'` to search for the literal string `$'`.

Answer (score 2):

This is bash's ANSI-C Quoting

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to *string*, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:

It's documented here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting